# Sorting by according column of array with linq in php

Tags: php, linq

I am absolutely beginner in php.
    I used linq_in_php to extract,sort,search data from array.

```
<?php
    include 'D3Linq.php';
    $a=new D3Linq();
    $cars = array(
        array("Volvo",22,18),
        array("BMW",15,13),
        array("Saab",5,2),
        array("Land Rover",17,15)
    );
    $a->Query("SELECT value As Sound FROM cars ORDER BY Sound DESC");
    echo 'Found '.$a->num_rows().' Element(s)<br>'; 
    while ($result=$a->fetch_object()){
         print_r($result);
    }
?>
```

I want to sort by according column.Eg, sort by first column Volvo,BMW,...
How do I sort?

Comment: What would be the order??

Comment: SELECT value As Sound FROM cars ORDER BY Sound = "Volvo", Sound = "BMW" .....

Comment: I means that three values in each room of $cars array.I want to order by all first values of each room.Now example array can fix.But my array is dynamic.